# Lagrangian of bead on a wire

Tags: physics

> A bead of mass $m$ slides (without friction) on a wire in the shape,
>   $y=b\cosh{\frac{x}{b}}.$
>
> 1. Write the Lagrangian for the bead.
> 2. Use the Lagrangian method to generate an equation of motion.
> 3. For small oscillations, approximate the differential equation neglecting terms higher than first order in $x$ and its derivatives.

I'm having trouble with the third part of the question. Here's my attempt at a solution:

It's pretty easy to find the Lagrangian. We have that potential energy of the bead is $$mgy=mgb\cosh{\frac{x}{b}}.$$ Kinetic energy is, $$\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2).$$ But $$y=b\cosh{\frac{x}{b}},$$ so $$\dot{y}=\sinh{\frac{x}{b}}\dot{x}.$$ So the Lagrangian is, $$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}m(1+\sinh^2{\frac{x}{b}})\dot{x}^2-mgb\cosh{\frac{x}{b}}.$$ Simplifying gives, $$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}m\cosh^2{\frac{x}{b}}\dot{x}^2-mgb\cosh{\frac{x}{b}}.$$

To do the second part we find the necessary derivatives:

$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial x}=\frac{m}{b}\cosh{\frac{x}{b}}\sinh{\frac{x}{b}}\dot{x}^2-mg\sinh{\frac{x}{b}}$$
$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{x}}=m\cosh^2{\frac{x}{b}}\dot{x}$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{x}}=2\frac{m}{b}\cosh{\frac{x}{b}}\sinh{\frac{x}{b}}\dot{x}+m\cosh^2{\frac{x}{b}}\ddot{x}$$

So, the Euler-Lagrange equation says,

$$\frac{m}{b}\cosh{\frac{x}{b}}\sinh{\frac{x}{b}}\dot{x}^2-mg\sinh{\frac{x}{b}}=2\frac{m}{b}\cosh{\frac{x}{b}}\sinh{\frac{x}{b}}\dot{x}+m\cosh^2{\frac{x}{b}}\ddot{x}$$ So the equation of motion is given by, $$\frac{\frac{m}{b}\cosh{\frac{x}{b}}\sinh{\frac{x}{b}}\dot{x}^2-mg\sinh{\frac{x}{b}}-2\frac{m}{b}\cosh{\frac{x}{b}}\sinh{\frac{x}{b}}\dot{x}}{m\cosh^2{\frac{x}{b}}}$$ I'm having trouble understanding what the third part of the question wants me to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to study the oscillations of the bead about $x=0$, which is a stable equilibrium point. To do this, we assume $x$ is very small and close to $0$. Under these approximations, $\cosh(\frac{x}{b})=1$ and $\sinh(\frac{x}{b})=\frac{x}{b}$. We must also make an additional approximation that $\dot{x}^2$ is small compared to $\dot{x}$. Substituting these in our equations of motion, we get
$$-mg\frac{x}{b}=m\ddot{x}$$
Which is that of a simple harmonic oscillator

Comment: The first term on the right-hand side can be disregarded as well, since it's second-order (combined) in $x$ and $\dot{x}$.  Also, I think you mean $\sinh(x/b) \approx x/b$, not $\sinh(x/b) \approx 1$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert corrected the answers